# how to style the SPAN element only on a popup, when the same element is present in the Parent page

Tags: html, css, popup

I have to style a SPAN differently on both,the parent page where it is present, and on the pop up which opens when we click on a link present on the parent page. If I change the styling through the css class, the style of SPAN on the parent page is getting affected. How do I select the SPAN on the POPUP only and not of the parent page. The page is share point page with some newsgator webparts added on it.
this is the SPAN class that is need to modify.

```
<span class="ngPresenceSpan">
<a title="" class="ngAuthorLink" target="_parent" authorid="" show="function(some jquery function here)
```

When I inspect through IE developer tools, in POPUP too, the same HTML is being rendered. I have to change the font and padding content with in  span .ngPresenceSpan only on POPUP

Comment: please add your code demo here

Comment: what  you want open a span on popup?

Comment: You can use attribute selector. @Deepika is this you want? http://jsbin.com/qofikasitu/1/edit

Comment: @Kheema, the link is blocked here in my office :(

Comment: let me put as answer then.

Answer (score 2):

@Deepika you can use CSS `[attribute]` Selector. check [DEMO](http://jsbin.com/qofikasitu/1/edit).

For example [*] will select the text `anch`.

```
span.ngPresenceSpan a[title*="anch"]{color:red;}
```

and HTML like this.

```
<span class="ngPresenceSpan">
<a title="anchor" class="ngAuthorLink" target="_parent" authorid="" show="function(some jquery function here)" href="#">
              TEXT                                                      </a>
  <p>&nbsp;</p>
 <span class="ngPresenceSpan">
  <a href="#" title="anch">Another same text in span</a> </span>
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick response Kheema,but, I have no access to the HTML file. I can only modify the css files. So in this case if I select the anchor tag, and apply the changes, it applies on the span in the parent page too. What i want is specifically and only the ID/class of SPAN on POPUP.

Comment: added the screens for better understanding.

Comment: @DeepikaTyagi seems screen is missing.

Comment: CSS specificity will play a major role here. Is the popup window have any special class or ID?  I guess class `.ngPresenceSpan` would be using somewhere else in page.. Right.. please share the Firebug screenshot.

Answer (score 0):

If i'm understand it correctly, then you should give an id to that specific SPAN element, then in the css you can style it. 
like:

```
<span id="popup-span">something</span>
```

then in the css:

```
#popup-span{
 //style here
}
```

Comment: I dont have access to the source code. I have to play around only on the css file.